# is it true that if we make any site in any cms, it may become heavy to load...compare to static

Tags: php, wordpress, xhtml, content-management-system

is it true that if we make any site in any cms, it may become heavy to load...

static html page **VS** page where content coming from databse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will take longer to serve pages from a database-based CMS than from a static HTML file on disk. However, most modern CMSes will mitigate this by providing some kind of cache. For example, the [WordPress Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin will cache your WordPress pages as static HTML and serve those, refreshing them when content changes, and [takes only a few minutes to set up](http://thingsthatarebrown.com/blog/2010/05/dont-get-fireballed/).

For my money, for anything other than trivial sites, the benefits of a CMS, with a cache system -- easy user updating, less repeating your code, still quite fast to load, etc. -- outweigh the costs.

There are also CMSes that you use locally, and then "burn" a set of static HTML files for upload, so you get the advantages of CMS management but the speed of static files, for example the Ruby-based [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true.
However, it doesn't matter anything.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true, do you have extra bandwidth, or extra CPU time?

Both use the same bandwidth initially. However CMS can more easily take advantage of extra bandwidth with AJAX (thinking of setting up the same AJAX in static HTML makes my skin crawl), which will also LOWER bandwidth usage.

A Cache System helps the CMS take more load off the CPU when CPU time is constrained.
Static HTML doesn't have many ways to use more CPU time without becoming non-static HTML.

Answer (score 1):

CMS are better to make a dynamic site only which are intracting with DB. Although i am satisfied with @Matt Gibson, But @Spilarix is also correct.

Moreover you can use a CMS for a different purpose. For example using wordpress to build ecommerce site instead of a blog. It'll save your time to build a robust and secure site.

Answer (score 0):

A static page will always be faster to load than a dynamic page even if you use cache.
Dynamism implies more calculations, data access, ...